# Why does there exist unique numbers $\varphi_1(v), \ldots, \varphi_m(v)$ such that $ Tv = \varphi_1(v)w_1 + \cdots + \varphi_m(v)w_m$?

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations, dual-spaces

**Exercise.**

Suppose $T \in \mathcal{L}(V,W)$ and $w_1,\ldots,w_m$ is a basis of $\text{range} \ T$. Hence for each $v \in V$, there exist unique numbers $\varphi_1(v), \ldots, \varphi_m(v)$ such that

$$
Tv = \varphi_1(v)w_1 + \cdots + \varphi_m(v)w_m,
$$

thus defining functions $\varphi_1, \ldots, \varphi_m$ from $V$ to $\mathbb{F}$. Show that each of the functions $\varphi_1, \ldots, \varphi_m$ is a linear functional on $V$.

---

**Source.**

Linear Algebra Done Right, Sheldon Axler, 4th Edition, Exercise 5. in Section 3F.

---

**My Question.**

I was able to show they're linear functionals by using the linearity of $T$. But my question has to do with the assumption taken in the exercise, that there does indeed exist unique numbers $\varphi_1(v), \ldots, \varphi_m(v)$ such that $Tv = \varphi_1(v)w_1 + \cdots + \varphi_m(v)w_m$.

I understand why they're unique is because $w_1, \ldots, w_m$ is a basis, but how do we know they are functions of $v$? Would that be easy to show? I might be forgetting an old result in the text.

Comment: For any $v \in V$, these scalars exist and are unique. Their specific value depends only on $v$. This makes them a function of $v$.

Comment: @TheoBendit Thanks for commenting. But I was wondering if we can rigorously show they are functions of $v$.

Comment: You know what linear functionals are, clearly. Has Axler defined the dual basis of a basis of $W$ yet? By “rigorous” you seem to require a formula, so my question is the route to that.

Comment: You might be overthinking this. The element $Tv$ depends on $v$ so, writing $Tv\in W$ as a linear combination of the basis elements depends on $Tv$ (which depends on $v$). In this problem, the existence of unique $\varphi_1(v), \dots, \varphi_m(v)$ is trivial if you understand what a basis is. The exercise is mostly showing that these functions are linear.

Comment: @TedShifrin Of $W$? I don't think so, only the dual basis of $V$. And then he introduced the annihilator. But I guess the dual basis of a basis of $W$ would just be a list of linear functionals that is a basis of the dual $W'$? Or is that incorrect?

Comment: @PaulAsh OK, how about this: the function $(a_1, \ldots, a_n) \mapsto a_1v_1 + \ldots a_n v_n$ is linear. Because $(v_1, \ldots, v_n)$ is a basis, this map is bijective, and thus has an inverse. Consider the projection maps $(a_1, \ldots, a_n) \mapsto a_i$ for any $i$. The $\varphi_i$ map is the inverse of the former map composed with the latter projection map.

Comment: Well, of course then you know what a dual basis is. Yes. If you use it, you can give an explicit formula for the $\varphi_i$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you agree that for every $v\in V$, there are unique scalars $a_1$, $a_2$, $\dots$, $a_m$ such that
$$Tv=a_1w_1+a_2w_2+\dots+a_mw_m$$
then we can define for each $1\leq i\le m$, a function $\phi_i\colon V\to \mathbb F$ as follows.

Remember what a function does is assigns a unique value in the codomain to each point in the domain. Take $v\in V$, then find **unique** scalars $a_i$s such that the above equation holds and then define $\phi_i(v)=a_i\in\mathbb F$.

Hence, the functions $\phi_i$ assigns a unique value in $\mathbb F$ to each point in $V$, and by definition of these functions, for any $v$ in $V$, we can write
$$Tv=\phi_1(v)w_1+\phi_2(v)w_2+\dots+\phi_m(v)w_m$$

Hope this helps. :)

Comment: Yes, thank you! It all seems so simple now haha. I was putting my brain in a knot last night.